# Unable to remove Dynamically generated content or bind it to proper location C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, tabs, dynamic-controls

I am trying to build a program that will allow me to generate dynamic tabs along with various text boxes, buttons and other entry fields. my current build is able to generate the tabs at the click of a button and it can technically remove them as well.

At this point, I decided to work on the "Remove" tab button; which while it functions technically (Adding itself to the newly generated tab and then later, removing a blank tab) the button remains persistently through all tabs in the program despite my best attempts to manually change it's parent, trying all the remove types, clear and dispose.

It just won't go away; which has been to say the least frustrating. I am concerned that if I do not address this issue it may afflict the other input fields once i try to establish them.

here is the logic that creates my new tab:

```
charTabs.TabPages.Insert(charTabs.TabPages.Count - 1, dLabel);
charTabs.SelectedIndex = charTabs.TabPages.Count - 2;
tabManager( (charTabs.SelectedIndex.ToString() ), dLabel, "create");
```

And this is the function I have been fighting with:

```
public void tabManager(string btnName,string tabName, string task)
    {
        Button delButton = new Button();

        if (task == "create")
        {
            Controls.Add(delButton); 
            delButton.Name = btnName;
            delButton.Tag = btnName; 
            delButton.Text = "Remove"; 
            delButton.BringToFront(); 
            delButton.Location = new Point(672, 512);// set to localation
            delButton.Parent = this.charTabs.SelectedTab;
            delButton.Visible = true;
            delButton.Click += delButton_Click;//Assign function
            //TODO Keep Generated Content on Tab when function is triggered
        }
        else if (task == "destroy")
        {
            charTabs.SelectedIndex = charTabs.TabPages.Count - 2;
            //TODO Delete Tab's Content
            charTabs.TabPages.Remove(charTabs.SelectedTab);

        }
    }
```

I greatly appreciate any help, as it's almost 5:00AM where I am and I have been banging my head against this for the better part of the weekend.